# How to rewrite data from a template in JSON?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have this model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('categories_url', args=[str(self.id)])

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Motobike(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And in view i do so..

```
class CategoryView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'bikes_site/categories_detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        category = self.get_object()
        context['motobikes'] =  Motobike.objects.filter(category_id=category.pk)
        return context
```

And display everythng in the template

```
{% for motobike in motobikes %}
    <ul>
        <p> Name:        {{ motobike.name }}</p>
        <p> Company:     {{ company.name }}</p>
        <p> Category:    {{ object.name }}</p>
        <p> Description: {{ object.description }} </p>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

How to rewrite it to be displayed in JSON format(such task)? It's necessary through HttpResponse.

Here's my test:

```
client = Client()

    category_id = Category.objects.get(name='Мотоциклы').id

    response = client.get(f'/categories/{category_id}/')

    assert response.status_code == 200

    response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

    assert len(response_data) == 2

    assert response_data[1]['name'] == 'Ninja Turbo'

    assert response_data[1]['vendor'] == 'Kawasaki'

    assert response_data[1]['category'] == 'Мотоциклы'

    assert response_data[1]['description'] == ''
```

How else to push the name of the company??

Comment: You're now using a `DetailView` which by default renders a `TemplateResponse`. Instead, you can override the `render_to_response()` method of your view to return a `JsonResponse`. Just pass it a dictionary of key/value pairs you want to see in the response and it'll send back JSON. Look [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#render_to_response) for the default `render_to_response()` that you want to replace.

Comment: and btw, your test doesn't need to decode and json.load the response: just `response_data = response.json()` will work.

Comment: I do like this:

class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'name': self.queryset})

And get an error:

Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Why?

Comment: because as the error says, a QuerySet is not serialisable. You can use Django's `serializer` to serialise the queryset ([link here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/)) and pass that to `JsonResponse`, but likely it won't be the format you want, in which case you can just serialise it yourself: loop through the queryset and serialise each object, `append` it to the `list` and then pass the list to `JsonResponse`

Comment: or easier: use `queryset = Category.objects.values('id', 'name', 'vendor', 'category')` so the query returns the list of objects as dictionary and `return JsonResponse({'object_list': list(queryset)})`

Comment: oh, thank u very much. And if i need to transfer the context, so that in json it would be:

assert response_data[1]['name'] == 'Ninja Turbo'

    assert response_data[1]['vendor'] == 'Kawasaki'

    assert response_data[1]['category'] == 'Мотоциклы'

    assert response_data[1]['description'] == ''

Comment: I don’t understand “transfer the context”. The response is just JSON. `response.json()` should be the list of objects and so you can just test `assert response.json()[1]['name'] == "something"`

Comment: The fact is that I need to write for this test.